# How to get the parent directory of a path string

Tags: vim

I want to do the same thing as the bash `dirname` command or python `os.path.split()[0]` in vimscript for any path string (not necessarily the path of the current file).

Sample desired behaviour:

- `/a/b/` -> `/a`
- `/a/b` -> `/a`

I have tried `fnamemodify()` but to me its output seems to depend on whether dirs exist or not:

```
:ec fnamemodify( '/usr/idontexist', ':p:h')
```

gives:

```
/usr
```

which is good, but:

```
:ec fnamemodify( '/usr/bin', ':p:h')
```

gives:

```
/usr/bin
```

which is not what I want, and I can't figure out what it is doing.

I hope to find a cross platform solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

have you read this part of the description of `:h`:

```
 When the file name ends in a path separator, only the path
            separator is removed. Thus ":p:h" on a directory name results
        on the directory name itself (without trailing slash).
```

that's the reason of:

```
:ec fnamemodify( '/usr/bin/', ':p:h')  "directory, ending with /
-> /usr/bin
:ec fnamemodify( '/usr/bin/', ':h')  "directory, ending with /
-> /usr/bin
:ec fnamemodify( '/usr/bin', ':p:h')  "directory, not ending with /
-> /usr/bin
:ec fnamemodify( '/usr/bin', ':h')  "directory, not ending with /
-> /usr
```

so there are two factors to decide the output.

- if your string ending with `separator`
- if you used `:p`

to achieve your goal, you may remove the last char if the string is ending with `/` (or `\ in win?)`, then pass to the function without `:p`

Comment: I think this was not the origin of my problem, but I was asking myself that anyways, so +1. what a complicated behaviour...

Comment: take my last comment back, this *was* the main cause of my problem! using `:p` is the problem not only because the dir may not exist, but because using `:p:h` does not do what I want. The fact that `:p` removed the `idontexist` part and seemed to do what I wanted falls inside undefined behaviour, and only confused me.

Answer (score 5):

```
fnamemodify( '/usr/idontexist', ':h')
```

The `:p` modifier will expand a path to a full path. Therefore it must be a real path. Just don't use `:p` if you are not messing with real paths.

See

```
:h filename-modifiers
```